# isrequestSent() in httpcomponent-core5

Tags: java, http, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpclient-5.x

How to know if the complete request has been sent over http using apache httpcomponent-core5 library. the same was available in httpcore-4 but the httpcorecontext "HTTP_REQ_SENT" has been removed without any explanation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: content is enough to be answered

Comment: httpcore-4 itself used this method for example to determine if a request should be retried in org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler.retryRequest(IOException, int, HttpContext) - with httpcomponent-core5 requests which previously would have been retried are not retried anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute and method were removed with https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1686588 - calling code was removed on the same day with https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1686589, with the commit message of the later commit my guess would be that one would not anymore want to retry non-idempotent methods and therefore decided to change the retry behavior.

I did not find a real replacement within the httpcore5 source code, if one really would want to monitor if header has already been sent one could think about writing a custom `org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.Http1StreamListener` (however this interface is also marked as internal - not sure if this is really a good idea) and use this within a customized `org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.HttpRequestExecutor` (see constructor there); the method `org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.Http1StreamListener#onRequestHead` is immediately called after `org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.HttpClientConnection#sendRequestHeader` has been called (during execution).

IMHO this would be close enough to the original attribute even though there is a difference, the original attribute was only set after `org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.BHttpConnection.flush()` had been called.